# getting error while following db connection details used in settings.py

Tags: mongodb, eve

while executing eve documentation example, I am getting
following error about database. Anybody know help me.
technologies are used eve framework and mongodb.
basic error so anybody can solve it.

```
settings.py
MONGO_HOST = 'localhost'
MONGO_PORT = 5000
MONGO_USERNAME = 'user'
MONGO_PASSWORD = 'user'
MONGO_DBNAME = 'apitest'

DOMAIN = {'people': {}}

error

(tornado_weber_env)weber@weber-desktop:~/tornado_weber_env/testing$ python run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "run.py", line 3, in 
app = Eve()
File "/home/weber/tornado_weber_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eve/flaskapp.py",        
line 136, in init
self.data = data(self)
File "/home/weber/tornado_weber_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eve/io/base.py",     
line 100, in init
self.init_app(self.app)
File "/home/weber/tornado_weber_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-    
packages/eve/io/mongo/mongo.py", line 73, in init_app
raise ConnectionException(e)
eve.io.base.ConnectionException: Error initializing the driver. Make sure the database    
server is running. Driver exception: OperationFailure(u"command SON([('authenticate', 1), 
('user', u'user'), ('nonce', u'6d4bfd537685c4b4'), ('key', 
u'f846d47fa6ee80a42807cc2e7bf8b8cf')]) failed: auth failed",)

(tornado_weber_env)weber@weber-desktop:~/tornado_weber_env/testing$ python run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "run.py", line 3, in 
app = Eve()

File "/home/weber/tornado_weber_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eve/flaskapp.py",   
line 136, in init

self.data = data(self)
File "/home/weber/tornado_weber_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eve/io/base.py",
line 100, in init
self.init_app(self.app)
File "/home/weber/tornado_weber_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-   
packages/eve/io/mongo/mongo.py", line 73, in init_app

raise ConnectionException(e)
eve.io.base.ConnectionException: Error initializing the driver. Make sure the database
server is running. Driver exception: Connection Failure('[Err no 111] Connection refused',)
```

Answer (score 0):

First verify that mongo is running on your machine, see [the Mongo documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/installation/). After do that in `setting.py` change the mongo information to your setup:

```
MONGO_HOST = 'localhost' # If your mongo server is locally running
MONGO_PORT = <port_to_your_mongo_server>
MONGO_USERNAME = ''
MONGO_PASSWORD = ''
MONGO_DBNAME = 'apitest'
```

Answer (score 0):

bumped into the same problem.

the username and password must be set to empty **''**

mongodb by default, starts with no authentication.

Thus, in **settings.py** set

MONGO_USERNAME = ''

MONGO_PASSWORD = ''